# What is the most loss suffered by a Hollywood movie?

Tags: film-industry

What Hollywood movie has lost the most money ever? How much did it lose? Is the answer different if you adjust for the value of money over time?

Comment: In reality or in terms of 'hollywood accounting'? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_accounting

Answer (score 9):

Wikipedia maintains a [list of box office bombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_box_office_bombs), that is movies that lost money.

As pointed out in the article, the numbers should be taken with a grain of salt, as it is not easy to estimate how much a movie has cost and earned without inside knowledge.

That being said, the current Top-5 from that page lists:

1. 47 Ronin *(2013)*, Estimated Loss: $149,518,763
2. Mars Needs Moms *(2011)*, Estimated Loss: $130,503,621
3. The 13th Warrior *(1999)*, Estimated Loss: $69,150,551—129,150,551
4. The Lone Ranger *(2013)*, Estimated Loss: $94,748,943—119,748,943
5. R.I.P.D. *(2013)*, Estimated Loss: $90,837,890—114,837,890

As you notice, most of those are pretty new. One reason for this might be that costs for production have increased over time, but there is also inflation (you cannot buy as much for 1 Dollar today as you could in 1950).

Fortunately, the same site also provides a list that has been adjusted for inflation. Here the Top 5 looks slightly different:

1. The 13th Warrior *(1999)*, $97,896,514—182,838,584
2. 47 Ronin *(2013)*, $151,923,973
3. Cutthroat Island *(1995)*, $137,346,554
4. Mars Needs Moms *(2011)*, $136,816,444

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted, in updating this question with to-date data, that Mortal Engines (2018) would seem to have topped the list:

From the [Mortal Engines Wiki page:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Engines_(film)#Box_office)

> Deadline Hollywood calculated the film lost the studio $174.8 million,
>   when factoring together all expenses and revenues, making it one of
>   the biggest box office bombs of all time.

This figure is supported on the link in the answer above.

Comment: O Holy Crap! That is an absolute buttload of money.  Who would have thought that the guy who gave us *The Lord of the Rings* and *The Hobbit* could bomb oh so hard